# How to restore Software Sources in System->Administration menu?

Tags: synaptic

Until Ubuntu 10.04 in System->Administration menu there was the "Software Sources" utility available. Now with Ubuntu 10.10 it's only accessible from Synaptic package manager. Is it possible to restore this functionality in Ubuntu 10.10 menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is right click the menu, open the menu editor, and add the item to your system menu.

The command you need to add is `gksu software-properties-gtk`
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Actually I had to click to the checkbox to enable it... no need to manually add the item. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: lol it's funny, I totally missed that =D

Answer (score 2):

It's also available inside the Software Center now, which is why it got removed from the menu I assume.

Comment: In the meny option "Edit->Software Sources..."

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the alacarte app. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then type `alacarte`